# Using FFmpeg filter without video conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, overlay

Does anyone have an idea of how I can put an image mask over the video without changing the audio & video codec?

I'm making different media files for testing purposes and I want control over my audio and video codecs used in a A/V container, now I need to put an image mask over a A/V file, without changing the audio and video codec.

When using `ffmpeg -i video.avi -i image.png -filter_complex 'overlay'  avi.mkv` I can add `-acodec copy` but not `-vcodec copy`, this gives the error:

> Streamcopy requested for output streaam 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.

And when just using the above command FFmpeg encodes my streams to another format (MPEG-4 & MP3)

Answer (score 9):

You answered your own question: filters are incompatible with `copy`. You're using a video filter there, so you can't use `-vcodec copy` or `-c:v copy`; if you were using an audio filter, you would be unable to to use `-acodec copy` or `-c:a copy`.

`copy`, as its name suggests, copies the stream specified exactly, with no changes. Filters alter the stream(s) they target. By definition, `copy` and filters are incompatible.

If you simply want to choose a specific video codec, then that's simple enough: use `-c:v [codecname]`; you can see a list of all the codecs your ffmpeg supports with

```
ffmpeg -codecs
```

Comment: However, this seems like bad architecture. E.g. what if I want to do a "setpts=2*PTS" filter to slow down the video. That should be able to run with only demuxing and muxing and should not require transcoding! (Because it's not accessing the pixel data, just the frame metadatas).

Comment: @EvolvedAI That's a good point, and ffmpeg has support for bit stream filters that *can* be used with stream copying. I suspect this is just a case of nobody has got around to writing a bit stream filter that does this, because it's a fairly niche use of ffmpeg, and outside of the tool's main purpose. Maybe you should raise this on the ffmpeg-users mailing list, and/or file a request on [their bug tracker](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg).

Comment: A workaround is to convert to a loss-less uncompressed file or post-processing format (e.g. dnxhd), or since this is for testing simply compress to very high quality. E.g. `-to 5 -crf 10` to create a 5sec high quality clip

Answer (score 1):

Since this is for testing simply set a codec with near original quality or even a post-processing format like *dnxhd*.

```
# Convert with near original quality compression
ffmpeg -i video.avi -i image.png -filter_complex 'overlay' -vcodec libx265 -crf 10 output.avi
```

We use libx265 since it yields very high quality video and highly available. A low CRF yields best results with 10 being near original video.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, it should be noted that there is probably a somewhat ugly way to do what you want by combining `ffprobe` and `ffmpeg` using bash. If you have `ffmpeg` installed, chances are you have `ffprobe` too. As a simple audio-only example, the following worked for me, though in principle something similar should be achievable with multiple streams of different kinds.

```
ffmpeg -i neil_young_tell_me_why.wav -af aresample=resampler=soxr:precision=33:cheby=true -ar 96000 -acodec `ffprobe -v error -show_entries:a:0 stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 neil_young_tell_me_why.wav | xargs echo -n` neil_young_tell_me_why_96Kup.wav
```

Explanation: The output of the `ffprobe` command within the backticks gets expanded in-place to stream 0 of the input file's audio codec, with the newline stripped off by `xargs`. `ffprobe` has been set to output a minimal amount of text, and the output of `ffprobe`'s default "writer" has been configured to strip out all other extraneous text, such as labels, etc, when writing to the screen.

I wanted to test higher quality resampling with the `SoX` resampler so I upsampled a wav file from 44.1KHz to 96KHz while keeping the same codec. Without doing it this way, the codec being chosen automatically by `ffmpeg` had a lower bit depth, causing the resolution to go down from 24 bit to 16 bit. This way there was no loss of precision.